# Using the universal property of K-theory

Tags: algebraic-k-theory

[A paper of Blumberg, Gepner and Tabuada](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.gt/1513732567) gives a universal property of K-theory: from their abstract "connective algebraic K-theory is the universal
additive invariant, i.e., the universal functor with values in spectra which inverts Morita equivalences, preserves filtered colimits, and satisfies Waldhausen’s additivity theorem".

Can this characterization be used to do (elementary) computations, e.g. can one reproduce the usual definition of $K_0$ of a category and maybe $K_1$ of a ring from this characterization?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can get the usual definition of $K_0$ of a stable ∞-category just from the universal property (since you can derived a universal property for $K_0$ from the universal property for $K$). I am very skeptical you can get the $K_1$ of a ring though.